# Get value from array and set select options on basis of that using JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, select

I have two arrays in php like this :

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 187
)
Array
(
    [0] => 118
    [1] => 112
    [2] => 85
    [3] => 81
    [4] => 119
    [5] => 82
)
```

these are basically two select fields values,i merged them into arrays so i can use them for my purpose.I am trying to get value form first array and match with second like if i get values of 11 from first array, it means from 0-4 index all have 11 and so on second array i have 5 values of `(0-4 index)`. And similarly if i get 118 from second array so get all values on first array.
if input `11 output will be => (118,112,85,81,119)` and similarly if input `187=>(82)`

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: Am I the only one who haven't understood anything from the last paragraph?

Comment: I am trying on select change to get first array value.But confuse on comparing the values

Comment: I believe what he meant was to get the value from array 1 that corresponds to the value in array 2.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman The arrays will be save with same key right?

Comment: @HarigovindR yes you are right on the basis of index of both arrays.

Comment: @HarigovindR. That's right but how it will relate each other?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Just give both under a single for loop since the value of key is the same for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help you. You can use same array functionality of PHP within JavaScript as

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    var one = [11,11,11,11,11,187];
    var two = [118,112,85,81,119,82];
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
        if(typeof result[one[i]] != 'undefined')
            result[one[i]].push(two[i]);
        else result[one[i]] = [two[i]];
    }
    console.log(result);
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$one = [11,11,11,11,11,187];
$two = [118,112,85,81,119,82];
$result = array();
foreach($one as $key => $value){
    $result[$value][] = $two[$key];
}
print_r($result);
```

Here `typeof` within JS is similar as of `isset` in PHP

Comment: Thanks i got the result on like this `console.log(result[11]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr1 = array(11,11,11,11,11,187);
$arr2 = array(118,112,85,81,119,82);
$input = 5;
$keysArr = array_keys($arr1, $arr1[$input]);
$newArr = array();
foreach ($keysArr AS $index) {
    $newArr[] = $arr2[$index];
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to get result in js as my input will be called on js.

Comment: You got the logic na. Use js syntax to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

JS code

```
var one = [11,11,11,11,11,187];
var two = [118,112,85,81,119,82];
var result = [];
var count = one.length;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
result[i] = one[i]+"=>"+two[i];
}
console.log(result);
```

> result = ["11=>118", "11=>112", "11=>85", "11=>81", "11=>119", "187=>82"]

Comment: Its not a proper answer. Actually its a workaround. But hope it helps you